# WCF Service vs Window service

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-services

Am a newbie to WCF.I have a scenario where i need to create  a application that runs 24x7  picks up mail from a mailbox and create few reports.I did it using winform and it worked.but i got a problem that the server on which the application was hosted has a auto log off policy which closes my application when server is inactive for a certain period of time.I thought i could implement it as a window service.Is WCF service recommended for this Scenario,any advantage of using it.I thought of WCF service since it will be learning curve for me.Please advice.

**Update**:
its application that works based on a timer.It pings a particular mailbox every 5 minutes to see for new mail.If a new mail is found it downloads an excel creates PDF report and mails it back to some email ids.

DLLS used : OpenPOP and Itextsharp.

Comment: You need to give us more details about what your application is intended for, other than "picks up mail from a mailbox and create few reports."

Comment: You would only need WCF if you have a client that is consuming your service

Answer (score 26, accepted):

A windows service is what you need.

WCF is a communications library, and unless you plan to communicate with your application via a client, you don't need it.

Your problem is related to activation, and keeping your code active in the background is what windows services do.

It's not difficult, this will help you get started.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/14353/Creating-a-Basic-Windows-Service-in-C

Comment: Good comment IanBru. I was just typing up the same response (+1). Here's a link to additional info from MS on the topic: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d56de412%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 3):

WCF is only useful if you're running a webservice.  Just a normal windows service should satisfy your needs here.  As long as the machine is up the service should keep running.

Comment: will window service run even if the user is logged off? i think it will.your thoughts? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If your application does what you want and works fine up until the server is in active, then you should consider solving the problem by setting up the server to not go into an inactive state.

In other words, since a server itself should never go into a standby (inactive) mode, my guess is that the policy that you speak of is only implemented for inactive *human* users - the policy probably (and shouldn't) affect the system level users.

So, if you were to run your application as a System user (or a Network user), the problem should go away.

Based on your explanation, WCF is not the right solution to your problem for two reasons:

1. WCF is useful for when you have another application (client) that consumes the WCF service) - It doesn't sound like you are in need of a client/server service in your app
2. If you were to run the WCF service as the same user as your current application is running under, your problem would still exist (i.e. the WCF service will be inactive eventually due to the policy).

Comment: that's a client machine and we have no permissions to change their server policies.what i mean by inactive mode is the server closes all application open by the users when there is no activity for a certain period.Any way to tackle this with out changing the server policy?

Comment: You will need to tell the client to run the service as System user (or Network). To see what I'm trying to explain, go to your Services then go to the Properties of any Service. Then, go to the "Log On" tab. You will notice that you can change the account that the service will run under.

Comment: service? i have not created a service.I did it as a windows application

Comment: Oh. Gotcha. The title of your post mentions "Window Service" - I assumed your application was a "Windows Service".

Comment: :-) no i was thinking to change it into a service.. seems window service is what i needed.thanks Jed

Comment: I see. A Windows Service is what you want. The one thing that you will need to know from the get-go, is the fact that a Windows Service does not allow you to use your Win Form.